# how do I change the result column based on the conditions of 2 columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

[image: database]
I tried the following but it didnt work. I am relatively new in pandas, any help is appriciated.

```
if(lambda x:df['HomeGoals']>df['AwayGoals']):
    df['Result']='H'
elif(lambda x:df['HomeGoals']<df['AwayGoals']):
    df['Result']='A'
else:
    df['Result']='D'
```

Comment: `df['Result'] = np.select( (df['HomeGoals']>df['AwayGoals'], df['HomeGoals']<df['AwayGoals']), ('H','A'), 'D')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try something new `np.sign`

```
df['R']=np.sign(df['HomeGoals']-df['AwayGoals']).map({1:'H',0:'D',-1:'A'})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to separate into a function

```
def calculate(reg):
    if reg['HomeGoals'] > reg['AwayGoals']:
        return 'H'
    elif reg['HomeGoals'] < reg['AwayGoals']:
        return 'A' 
    else:
        return 'D'

df['Result'] = df.apply(calculate, axis=1)
```